# Create dynamic table field

Tags: javascript

I have create table from javascript from prompt. But i need to 2 input field rows/columns and need to generate table based on setting value on input

You can see code below which i have tried using javascript prompt already.

```js
    var rows = prompt("How many rows for your multiplication table?");
    var cols = prompt("How many columns for your multiplication table?");
    if(rows == "" || rows == null)
      rows = 10;
    if(cols== "" || cols== null)
      cols = 10;
    createTable(rows, cols); // function initialize
    function createTable(rows, cols)
    {
      var j=1;
      var output = "<table border='1' width='500' cellspacing='0'cellpadding='5'>"; // to create table element
      for(i=1;i<=rows;i++) // loop for generate rows
      {
     output = output + "<tr>";
        while(j<=cols)
        {
      output = output + "<td>" + i*j + "</td>"; // to create cells
       j = j+1;
     }
      output = output + "</tr>";
      j = 1;
    }
    output = output + "</table>";
    document.write(output);
    }
```

Comment: You can simply do `output += ...` instead of `output = output + ...`

Comment: you can use intput fields instead of prompts

Comment: what's the problem here? i don't spot any

Comment: i need to work via inputs. Can you update with this code please?

Comment: @Kumar Please try it with input, add your efforts and we can help you when you stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here the code for generate dynamic table by user inputs. comments in the code describe furthermore

```js
function generate() {

  //remove current table
  var tbl = document.getElementById("myTable");
  if (tbl)
    tbl.parentNode.removeChild(tbl);

  var rows = document.getElementById('rows').value;
  var cols = document.getElementById('cols').value;

  if (rows == "" || rows == null)
    rows = 10;
  else
    rows = +rows; //convert to integer

  if (cols == "" || cols == null)
    cols = 10;
  else
    cols = +cols; //convert to integer

  //add a table element
  var table = document.createElement("TABLE");
  table.setAttribute("id", "myTable");
  table.setAttribute("border", "1");
  table.setAttribute("width", "500");
  table.setAttribute("cellspacing", "0");
  table.setAttribute("cellpadding", "5");
  document.body.appendChild(table);

  for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {

    //create a table row    
    var row = table.insertRow(i);

    for (var j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
      //create cell
      var cell = row.insertCell(j);
      cell.innerHTML = 'cell ' + i + ' ' + j;
    }

  }

}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  No of rows: <input type="text" id="rows"> <br> No of Columns: <input type="text" id="cols"> <br>
  <button id="generate-table" onClick="generate()">Generate</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update the table via `input` just replace the `prompt` with the input tags value and generate the Multiplication table. Are you looking for the snippet like below?

```js
function maketable(){
  var rows =document.getElementById("row").value;
  var cols = document.getElementById("col").value;
  if(rows == "" || rows == null)
    rows = 10;
  if(cols== "" || cols== null)
    cols = 10;
  createTable(rows, cols); // function initialize
  function createTable(rows, cols)
  {
    var j=1;
    var output = "<table border='1' width='500' cellspacing='0'cellpadding='5'>"; // to create table element
    for(i=1;i<=rows;i++) // loop for generate rows
    {
      output = output + "<tr>";
      while(j<=cols)
      {
        output = output + "<td>" + i*j + "</td>"; // to create cells
        j = j+1;
      }
      output = output + "</tr>";
      j = 1;
    }
    output = output + "</table>";
    document.getElementById("table-data").innerHTML = output;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>JS Bin</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    Row: <input type="number" id="row" class="row-number"></input>
  Column: <input type="number" id="col" class="row-column"></input>
  <button onclick="maketable()">Generate</button>
  <br><br>
  <div id="table-data">


  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is a textbook gimme teh codez question. Why are you doing all the work for him? You should encourage learning, not just outright doing the work for OP.

Comment: @FrankerZ I am sorry! He asked and I did it

Comment: @FrankerZ please just avoid if you don't want to answer at all. Its not codeschool/codeacademy or udemy its community of developer so i can ask when i got issues. You don't need to encourage please just............ I know what should i do?